# Hide table scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar, css-tables

After some researches I found out that I have to set the tbody of a table

```
display: block;
overflow: auto;
```

to enable scrolling on a html table.

Is there a possibility to hide the scrollbar generic on every modern browser (Chrome, Safari, Firefox)? I tried some solutions like [this one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari.aspx) but it doesn't work on a table.

Comment: have you tried `overflow: none;`

Comment: But my aim is that the table is scrollable and the scrollbars are't visible. When I am apply overflow: none; to the tbody it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post fiddle with your problem? Hard to solve something I can't see.

Answer (score 5):

Use `overflow: hidden;` to hide the content outside of the container, or `overflow: visible;` to display it even if it's going outside of the container borders. Both remove the scrollbar.

Comment: Or maybe you want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll ?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove scrollbar easily by using the following CSS class:

```css
.overflow-hidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

If you are using Bootstrap just use overflow functionality. Find docs [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/overflow/)

```
<div class="overflow-hidden">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the next css code

```
/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: transparent;
}
```

We hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```css
.hideScrollbar::-webkit-scrollbar{
  display: none; 
 }
```

```html
<div class='hideScrollbar'></div>
```