# How can I hide the vertical scrollbar in jquery datatable

Tags: datatables, scrollbar, hide

I'm trying to hide the vertical scrollbar not the scroll functionality in data tables:

I've tried to hide the scrollbar using css but it is increasing the overall width of the parent container.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide table scrollbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29606799/hide-table-scrollbar)

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! You need to share with us what you've tried to achieve the desired output. Can you provide a **[minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)**?

Answer (score 0):

You can write: "scrollY": false